# sound.stop() does not work , but sound.play() is working in Howlerjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, howler.js

I am trying to use Howler.js in Reactjs using typescript.

I can able to play the sound but it does not pause or stop. Here is my code.

This a component where I am passing all the audio details using props.
I did console.log() to check, is it going in else part and it goes and print the console.
Please help me in this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from 'components/button/button';
import PlayIcon from 'assets/icons/play.svg';
import PauseIcon from 'assets/icons/pause.svg';
import AudioWave from 'assets/icons/sound-wave.svg';
import { Howl, Howler } from 'howler';   
interface Props {
    name?: string,
    audio?: any,
    loop?: boolean,
    autoplay?: boolean
}

const Audio = (props: Props) => {
    const { name, audio, loop, autoplay } = props;
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
    const [audioId, setAudioId] = useState(0);
    const sound = new Howl({
        src: [audio],
        autoplay: autoplay,
        loop: loop,
        volume: 1,
        onend: function () {
            setIsPlaying(false);
        },
    });
    Howler.volume(0.5);

    const playAudio = () => {
        let Id: any;
        if (!isPlaying) {
            Id = sound.play();
            setAudioId(Id);
            setIsPlaying(true);
            console.log('THS')
        } else {
            sound.stop(audioId);
            console.log('THATAT', audioId)
        }
        console.log(sound)
    }

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center rounded shadow-md w-full">
            {console.log(isPlaying, audioId)}
            <div className="grid grid-cols-12 w-full">
                <div className="col-span-6 p-2">
                    <p className="text-left">
                        {name}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className="col-span-6 p-2">
                    <p className="text-right text-light-gray">
                        {sound ? `${Duration.toTimeFormat(sound._duration * 1000)}s` : '0:00s'}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-12 w-full items-center justify-center">
                <div className="grid col-span-2 w-full p-2">
                    <img
                        className="w-full cursor"
                        onClick={() => playAudio()}
                        src={isPlaying ? PauseIcon : PlayIcon}
                        alt="PlayPauseIcon"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="grid col-span-10 p-2">
                    <img className="w-full" alt="Audio Wave" src={AudioWave} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Audio;
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging by passing in a function for the `onPause` function to the Howler constructor? [docs](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#onpause-function). Then, you could see if the callback is getting called at least.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Howler, but it seems it's not 'react-friendly' - more suited for a non-SPA environment. However, I figure if you try it like this, you might get the results you're looking for. The main issue with your code is that every time you change something via `useState`, the component will re-render. When it re-renders, any variables that are not stored via `useState`, will have their values re-initialized. Therefore, in your code from the question, the `sound` variable gets reset on every render making it impossible to control the element. In the code below I shifted that into a `useEffect` function, which is similar to `componentDidMount`. It will only run on the first render; thus, it prevents you from having several copies of the sound object.

I haven't tested this code, but I think in general it targets the main issue you're having.

```
const Audio = (props: Props) => {
  const { name, audio, loop, autoplay } = props;
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [audioId, setAudioId] = useState(0);
  const [sound, setSound] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const s = new Howl({
      src: [audio],
      autoplay: autoplay,
      loop: loop,
      volume: 0.5,
      onplay: function (id) {
        setAudioId(id);
        setIsPlaying(true);
      },
      onpause: function (id) {
        setIsPlaying(false);
      },
      onend: function () {
        setIsPlaying(false);
      },
      onloaderror: function(id, error) {
        console.log(`a load error has occured on id ${id}`);
        console.error(error);
      },
      onplayerror: function(id, error) {
        console.log(`a play error has occured on id ${id}`);
        console.error(error);
      }
    });

    setSound(s);
  });

  const toggleAudioState = () => {
    if (sound !== null) {
      if (!isPlaying) {
        sound.play();
        setIsPlaying(true);
      } else {
        sound.stop(audioId);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center rounded shadow-md w-full">
      <div className="grid grid-cols-12 w-full">
        <div className="col-span-6 p-2">
          <p className="text-left">
            {name}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-6 p-2">
          <p className="text-right text-light-gray">
            {sound ? `${Duration.toTimeFormat(sound._duration * 1000)}s` : '0:00s'}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-12 w-full items-center justify-center">
        <div className="grid col-span-2 w-full p-2">
          <img
            className="w-full cursor"
            onClick={() => toggleAudioState()}
            src={isPlaying ? PauseIcon : PlayIcon}
            alt="PlayPauseIcon"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="grid col-span-10 p-2">
          <img className="w-full" alt="Audio Wave" src={AudioWave} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for that : -

Here it should be define global. But we can't do it in react, because we are receiving all the data through props.

```
const sound = new Howl({ } );
```

If we define this able the function then it will work -

```
const sound = new Howl({
    src: ['some_music_link.mp3'],
    autoplay: true,
    loop: true,
    volume: 1,
});
const Audio = (props :Props) => {
...
}
```

In order to solve this problem someone created a **new npm package** for that called [Router Howler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-howler/)

So, if you are trying to use howler.js in react then use [React Howler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-howler/)